# Automatically unwrapping wrapped object in Groovy

Tags: groovy, scripting, delegates

I have an object which I pass into Groovy scripts via binding. There are hundreds of implementations of this object (think "POJO") which all implement a common interface.

I created the wrapper in the first place to be able to say `pojo.property` since I have 2-3 three ways to look up properties for these in Java and that was cumbersome in Groovy scripts. So I created a wrapper which wraps the original object and implements `getProperty()` and the rest of the MOP to simulate objects which have all those properties from all the possible sources.

This works great. But now, I need to call methods with this wrapper. The methods, of course, are implemented in Java and have no idea that Groovy exists or that there might be a wrapper. There are thousands of these methods. The simple solution is to add a method to the wrapper:

```
public static IPojo unwrap(IPojo pojo) {
    if( pojo instanceof GroovyPojoWrapper) return ((GroovyPojoWrapper)pojo).getDelegate();

    return pojo;
}
```

which would allow me to:

```
def dao = appContext[ FooDao ];
dao.save( unwrap( pojo ) );
```

While that would work, I now need to call this in thousands of places and help me (insert diety of your choice here) if I miss one.

Which got me wondering if there wasn't a better solution. Namely:

```
public class Foo extends IPojo {}

public class FooDao {
    public void save( Foo foo ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do this in my script:

```
def dao = appContext[ FooDao ];
dao.save( pojo ); // <-- How to unwrap here?
```

Is there a way to make Groovy automatically unwrap an object when I call a method?

Comment: Is everything wrapped?  ie: would `dao.save( pojo.delegate );` work? Or are some things not wrapped?  Maybe wrapping the `dao.save` method is an option?  Are there less daos than pojos? ;-)

Comment: There is one DAO per POJO but each DAO has N methods and there are other Spring beans which accept POJOs as arguments. The object behind the name `pojo` is always wrapped but I might do `def list = barDao.findRelated(pojo)` and the elements of the list would be pure POJOs (not wrapped) unless I can find a way to wrap them without changing `BarDao.findRelated()`.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be possible to achieve something like this with an AST transformation but I haven't done those before and I wonder how the AST transformation could know the runtime type.

Comment: Maybe just decorating the metaClass of the POJO instead of setting the delegate would help?  Then it remains a POJO for when you send it to Java (as it has no concept of the metaClass), but you can get at your extra methods in Groovy?

Comment: @tim_yates: That's an interesting idea. How can I add a property lookup to a metaClass?

Comment: Something like this? http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/groovy-goodness-override-getproperty.html

Comment: @tim_yates: That looks very promising. Now a slight setback: For some property lookups, I need an additional variable from the current binding. Can I access the current script binding from the closure that I put into the metaClass?

Comment: @tim_yates: Alternatively, I guess I could use a ThreadLocal but I'd like to avoid that, if possible. Is there a way to create a Groovy "environment" per script execution where each has a different `getProperty()` method in the metaClass?

Comment: Not sure...  I think we need a small example app...  It *should* be possible to get the current binding from the closure, but I've never tried and may be wrong

Comment: I'll try to come up with a prototype but probably not today.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem completely, but if what you want is to be able to tell Groovy that it's alright to call `save` not only on the Pojo, but also on the Pojo wrapper object, then you can do this:

Java class:

```
public class Dao {

  public void save( Foo foo ) {
      System.out.println( foo );
  }

}
```

Groovy script:

```
class FooWrapper {
  Foo foo
}

// tell Groovy how to unwrap anything that comes in wrapped when being saved
Dao.metaClass.save { FooWrapper wrapper -> save( wrapper.foo ) }

def foo = new Foo()
def wrappedFoo = new FooWrapper( foo: foo )

def dao = new Dao()

dao.save( foo )
dao.save( wrappedFoo )
```

Both save calls work now. Of course, Java does not know about metaClass so this only works when the save call is in Groovy code.